# Why is go-ethereum reporting very small block sizes?

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain

I am running a full `geth` node and was interested in the blockchain size.

Therefore, I compared the sum of all blocks' sizes with the actual disk size the blockchain copy consumes.

While the `chaindata` folder is 136 GiB large, the sum over all block sizes is just under 5 GiB. Where does this difference come from?

**Obtaining Disk Size**

```
$ du -hs geth/chaindata/
136G    geth/chaindata/
```

**Obtaining Block Sizes**

Here, I use the JSON-RPC interface and query each block (`eth_getBlockByHash`), going backwards from the best block I know (using the `eth_getBlockByNumber` API call).

From each block, I get the `size` value (which is in bytes according to [the wiki](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_getblockbyhash)).
However, the sum of all `size` attributes is only roughly 4.76 GiB.

What am I missing here?

*(I know I could just fetch each block by its number, but this is irrelevant for the question.)*

Answer (score 3):

The difference you're seeing is due to the state data, which is stored separately to the block data.

The blocks themselves are composed of a header, a list of the contained transactions, and a list of ommers. This is the *block data*. This accounts for your ~5GB value.

All other data - e.g. account data, such as contract code, balances, nonces, together with other data, such as logs and receipts - is considered *state data*, and not kept in the blocks themselves. (It is still downloaded by all "full" nodes.) This accounts for the remaining ~130GB you're seeing.

For further details on this, see the following:

[Where is the state data stored?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/359/where-is-the-state-data-stored)

Also perhaps of use is the below picture, from the following previous thread:

[Ethereum block architecture](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/268/ethereum-block-architecture)

The block itself is shown on the right, with the header containing values derived from the state data, which is shown in the big square box in the middle.

[image]

**Note:**

I got a similar figure of ~5GB by downloading a CSV of the average block sizes from Etherscan, and extrapolating for the number of blocks per day given an average block time: https://etherscan.io/chart/blocksize

Comment: nice graphe could you please share its source with me?

Comment: The source is this answer: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/6413/52. It was made by the person who answered that question :-)

Answer (score 1):

Are you on a Mac?  It's my experience that 'du' on Mac will report significantly larger disc usage than you would get by adding up file sizes in bytes. Search Google. You'll see.